# How can I convert a model's rigging from standard bones to a biped in 3DS Max?

Tags: 3dsmax

I've purchased a rigged 3D model from Turbosquid. Unfortunately the model has been rigged using standard bones instead of a biped.

Is the a way I can automatically converting the skinning from bones to biped?

Comment: This sounds like a good question to me, don't apologize :) 3DSMax + Biped, this sound quite gamedev-related.

Comment: Just curious, did you try this first [google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=converting+the+skinning+from+bones+to+biped&oq=converting+the+skinning+from+bones+to+biped&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), [Mixamo Auto-Biped script](http://www.mixamo.com/c/mixamo-auto-biped-script)?

Comment: Extremely good suggestion. Gonna try this out.

Comment: @seth You have 24 hours to make it into an answer. :)

Comment: I emailed and invited those Mixamo folks to write an authoritative answer about their tool.  If they don't show up, I'll post something.  Mine will be full of caveats about never having used the thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there's a company called [Mixamo](http://www.mixamo.com/) that sells and constructs anthropomorphic models as a service.  And their web interface handles rigging.  And it's fairly expensive, with a very brief free trial.

But assuming you get it right on one of those first two tries, you should be able to import one of their "auto-rigged" models back into 3dsmax, and run a [free max script that will convert it to biped rigging](http://content.mixamo.com/Mixamo_Autobiped.zip).

I assume this script relies on their automatic rigging conventions in order to function, but it starts with a list of bodypart ids as constants.  So perhaps you could tweak those values, or otherwise prep your own model, and run the script in isolation.  In any case, perhaps it would give you some insight in how to go about converting the model manually.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Seth! Feel free to answer one of the many other unanswered questions on the site.